# Is there an easier way to package with Python?

Tags: python, django, installation, package, pip

I tried to package a django app today. It's a big baby, and with the setup file, I have to manually write all packages and sub packages in the 'package' parameter. Then I have to find a way to copy fixtures, htmls / Css / image files, documentations, etc.

It's a terrible way to work. We are computer scientists, we automatize, doing this makes no sense.

And what when I change my app structure ? I have to rewrite the setup.py.

**Is there a better way ? Some tool to automate that ?** I can't believe a language than value developer time like Python makes packaging such a chore.

I want to be able to eventually install the app using a simple pip install. I know about build out, but it's not much simpler, and is not pip friendly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the very least if you use [`setuptools`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/) (an alternative to the stdlib's `distutils`) you get an awesome function called [`find_packages()`](http://nullege.com/codes/search/setuptools.find_packages/derive) which when ran from the package root returns a list of package names in dot-notation suitable for the `packages` parameter.

Here is an example:

```
# setup.py

from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    #...
    packages=find_packages(exclude='tests'),
    #...
)
```

p.s. Packaging sucks in every language and every system. It sucks no matter how you slice it.

Comment: Do you have such a tip for satic files such as po, html/css and doc that I have to include manually as well ? Maybe setuptools.findall ? If you do, I accept your anwser.

Comment: You can specify those using the `package_data`  (http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data) or `data_files`.(http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files) parameters.  For the example, if `data_files` is set to `[('share/mypackage', ['test.html'])]`, upon installation `test.html` will be copied into `/usr/share/mypackage` (assuming your prefix is `/usr/share`).

Comment: It's not a silver bullet, but it's the best anwset so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I've been through this pain myself today. I used the following, yoinked straight from [Django's setup.py](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/setup.py), which walks the app's filesystem looking for packages and data files (assuming you never mix the two):

```
import os
from distutils.command.install import INSTALL_SCHEMES

def fullsplit(path, result=None):
    """
    Split a pathname into components (the opposite of os.path.join) in a
    platform-neutral way.
    """
    if result is None:
        result = []
    head, tail = os.path.split(path)
    if head == '':
        return [tail] + result
    if head == path:
        return result
    return fullsplit(head, [tail] + result)

# Tell distutils to put the data_files in platform-specific installation
# locations. See here for an explanation:
# http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/browse_thread/thread/35ec7b2fed36eaec/2105ee4d9e8042cb
for scheme in INSTALL_SCHEMES.values():
    scheme['data'] = scheme['purelib']

# Compile the list of packages available, because distutils doesn't have
# an easy way to do this.
packages, data_files = [], []
root_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
if root_dir != '':
    os.chdir(root_dir)
myapp_dir = 'myapp'

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(myapp_dir):
    # Ignore dirnames that start with '.'
    for i, dirname in enumerate(dirnames):
        if dirname.startswith('.'): del dirnames[i]
    if '__init__.py' in filenames:
        packages.append('.'.join(fullsplit(dirpath)))
    elif filenames:
        data_files.append([dirpath, [os.path.join(dirpath, f) for f in filenames]])
```

Comment: This is brillant ! I will try this. If it works, I'll accept the anwser.

Answer (score 0):

I think the tool you are looking for is [Buildout](http://www.buildout.org/). There lots of places where you can learn more about it, from [SlideShare](http://www.slideshare.net/claytron/using-buildout-to-develop-and-deploy-python-projects) to [Pycon videos](http://pycon.blip.tv/file/2061520/).

Other similar or related tools which you might want to check out include [virtualenv, Fabric, and PIP](http://www.clemesha.org/blog/modern-python-hacker-tools-virtualenv-fabric-pip).

Comment: Can you pip install something packaged with buildout ? I don't want to provide a package that need more that a pip install in a virtualenv.

Comment: Searched. Yes you can. But my, buildout is everything but easy to use. It's huge, with spare documentation and based on text file instead of python files.

Comment: I can't disagree with your description, I think you're spot on. I just don't know what else to recommend that fits any better :(

Answer (score -1):

I've been doing a bit of research myself on Django deployment methods recently.

I found these two resources very useful:

- http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2010/04/22/basic-django-deployment-with-virtualenv-fabric-pip-and-rsync/ - A basic overview of how to use virtualenv, pip and fabric to do easy Django deployment from dev machine to production.
- https://github.com/jacobian/django-deployment-workshop/ - Jacob(ian) did a Django deployment workshop, with all the code posted on GitHub. All the necessary links are there as well.

Comment: This is not helpfull at all for this question. Deployment is perfectly ok to me. Packaging is the annoying part.

Comment: The links I posted give some good insight on packaging methods as well. I'm sorry you didn't find the links useful and decided to downvote.